# Как сделать полученное значение из базы данных жирным (pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Возможности телеграма позволяют задать стили текста через разметку html или markdown.
То есть например:

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '*bold*',parse_mode='markdown')
```

В результате мы получим такой текст: **bold**

Вопрос как сделать текст таким, если я получаю его через запрос в базу данных, например:

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, db.get_subscriptions2(message.from_user.id), parse_mode='markdown')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = db.get_subscriptions2(message.from_user.id)
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'*{data}*', parse_mode='markdown')
```

Comment: Благодарю! Не подскажите еще вопрос, не нашел в официальной документации, как сделать вид текста под код? жирный, италик везде есть, а примеров под "код" мало

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог то вы можете отметить его как правильный) А по поводу комментария то лучше создайте новый вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, отметил!